# Integrable functions with sequences of functions (real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

**Problem Statement:** Let $\phi_n$ be a sequence of nonnegative functions that are Riemann integrable over [-1,1]. Additionally, they satisfy the following properties:  $\\$
$$(a) \ \int_{-1}^{1} \! \phi_n(t) \, \mathrm{d}t=1 \ \mathrm{for \ every} \ n$$ 
$\\$ (b) for every $\delta>0$, $\phi_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on [1,-$\delta$]$\cup$[$\delta$,1]. $$\\$$
Show that for ever $f$ which is integrable over [-1,1] and continuous at $0$, we have 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-1}^{1} \! f(t)\phi_n(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \rightarrow f(0) $$
$$ $$
**My attempt:** So far, since we have that that $\phi_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on  [1,-$\delta$]$\cup$[$\delta$,1] (and hence we can use the term-by-term integration theorem for sequences, I have been able to show that the above integral reduces to
$$  \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \! f(t) \lim_{n \to \infty}\phi_n(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$$ Then, I was thinking that either the fundamental theorem of calculus or something similar should be used to complete the proof, but I am not sure how I would go about doing that. Ideas? Suggestions? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Or could we prove it using the $\epsilon$ definition of convergence?

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim_n \phi_n(t)$? Limit might not exist.

Comment: If you mean in the last expression, I mean that I interchanged integration with limits because the sequence uniformly converges. I am not sure what would happen between [-$\delta$,$\delta$]

Comment: So far I have not used the fact that $\phi$ integrates to 1 and the fact that it's a sequence of nonnegative functions.

Comment: In order to interchange limit and integration, at least you need that limit of the integrand exist. Indeed from the condition of $\phi_n$, the limit should goes to $0$ except possibly at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1: Using $\int_{-1}^1 \phi_n(t) dt = 1$,

$$ \int_{-1}^1 f(t) \phi_n(t) dt - f(0) = \int^1_{-1} \big(f(t) - f(0)\big) \phi_n (t) dt .$$

The left hand side is something you want to bound.

Hint 2: We split the right hand side to three parts:

$$\int^1_{1-\delta} + \int_{-\delta}^\delta + \int_{-1}^{-1+\delta} \big(f(x) - f(0)\big) \phi_n(t) dt\ .$$

What happens to the middle term?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Yeah, I see how we'd like to bound the LHS. Would we then reduce the bounds of integration to [-$\delta$,$\delta$] since $phi$ converges to zero outside of that interval? I appreciate your suggestion :)

Comment: Exactly! Now I edit the post.

Comment: Cool! Well, withing [-δ,δ] we only know that $\phi$ is positive, but letting $\delta$ go to zero, i.e. shrinking down the interval over which we integrate, should also make the middle term go to zero, I guess.

Comment: Then how do you use the fact that $f$ is continuous at $0$?

Comment: if $f$ is continuous at zero that means that $f(0)$ is finite so that the integral is a proper integral as $\delta$ shrinks (feel free to correct me if I am wrong please)

Comment: If $f$ is continuous at $0$. Then $f(t) - f(0)$ would be very small. I suggest that we fix $\delta$ and let $n$ varies. The reason is that, if the make $\delta$ shrinks to $0$, although the middle can be killed, but then you cannot control the other two terms.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11579/discussion-between-johnsteck-and-john)